# matlab app designer load image in new app

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am using `App Designer` and trying to load an image (after clicking on it) from MainApp to App2 and show it directly (see screenshot) using a global variable in MainApp called `imagePath`, where I store the string ('metro-station.png') and a `Startup function` within App2, where I set the ImageSource to that path.

But it doesn't seem to work.

```
function startupFcn(app)
    app.Image.ImageSource = fullfile(imagePath);
end
```

[image]

Is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You don’t need `global variable` to share data between two Apps.

One of the possible way to exchange data between Apps is:

**In the MainApp**:

- Define a `public property` (the variable that you want to share with the second App)
- Initialize it in a function or callback of the MainApp
- When calling the second App, just pass the “App” handle as input parameter, this allows sharing all the public properties of the MainApp to the second App

**In the second App:**

- Define a `private property` to hold the input parameter coming from the MainApp
- In the `startupFcn` assign the input parameter to such property
- From this moment on, you can access to all the `public properties` of the ManApp, including the specific one you want to pass from the MainApp to the second App

One of the pros (but, at the same time, one of the cons) of this method is that you can modify any of the MainApp public properties in the second App, especially the input parameter

If you don’t want (don’t need) to give to the second App the possibility to modify the MainApp properties:

**In the MainApp:**

- if you want to change the input parameter for the Second App inside other functions besides the one where you call Second App, you can define it as `private property` in the MainApp so that you can access to it in any MainApp `function / callback`
- Otherwise you can define a `local variable` in the `function` / `callback` of the MainApp calling the second App and use it as input parameter
- Then, when calling the Second App you can pass only this `property` or the `local` variable to the second App

**In the second App:**

- Define a `private property` in which to store the input parameter
- In the s`tartupFcn` assigns the input `parameter` to that `property`
- From this moment on, all the second App function / callback have access to the ManApp input parameter

The pros (but, at the same time, the cons) of this method is that:

- Since the input parameter is passed by value, any modification to the input parameter is lost when you close the second App
- The second App does not have access to the public properties of the MainApp

Other sharing methods are available.

In the solution proposed in the below code, I’ve used (for simplicity) the first approach.

The `MainApp` presents 6 `Images` and the `Import pushbutton` that, when pressed, opens the `second App` and displays the image selected in the MainApp:

- The image is selected by clicking on it, when selected, the Selected (click again to unselect) label appears above it
- Clicking again on the image, deselect the image
- Clicking another image, selects the image and deselects the image selected before (if any)
- The pushbutton is enabled only if an image has been selected, when pressed, the second App opens.

The `second App` simply displays the image selected in the MainApp, a `Close pushbutton` allows to close it.

The MainApp consists of: (see below picture):

- 6 Image objects: app.Image1, …
- 6 Labels: app.img_1_selected, …
- 1 pushbutton: app.ImportButton

[image]

The app2 consists of (see below picture):

- 1 Image object: app.Image
- 1 Label: app.Label
- 1 pushbutton: CloseButton

[image]

**MainApp code**

For simplicity the path and the filename of the images in the MainApp are hardcoded, but you can easily implement a function to dynamically load them.

In the set of `public properties` you can find, among the others:

- `PathSelectedImage`: the property used to store the path and the filename of the selected image to be passed to the second App
- `ImgSelectionStr`: an array to store the handles of the labels of the images
- `ImageSet`: an array to store the handles of the image object

These two arrays allows using for loops when working with the images and the string and to avoid code duplications.

The arrays are initialized in the startupFcn function.

To access to the properties of the objects stored in the arrays you have to use the [set](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) / [get](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) functions instead of the [dot notation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/identify-data-using-dot-notation.html).

The `ImageClickedFcn callback` is defined for each image; it simply sets the ID of the image and calls the `SetUnset_Selection` function.

The `SetUnset_Selection function` manages the selection of the images, the label above them and enables / disables the `Import pushbutton`

```
classdef MainApp_exported < matlab.apps.AppBase

   % Properties that correspond to app components
   properties (Access = public)
      MainAppUIFigure  matlab.ui.Figure
      img_1_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      img_2_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      img_3_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      img_4_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      img_5_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      img_6_selected   matlab.ui.control.Label
      ImportButton     matlab.ui.control.Button
      Image_6          matlab.ui.control.Image
      Image_5          matlab.ui.control.Image
      Image_4          matlab.ui.control.Image
      Image_3          matlab.ui.control.Image
      Image_2          matlab.ui.control.Image
      Image_1          matlab.ui.control.Image
   end

   properties (Access = public)
      PathSelectedImage;   % Path and filename of the selected image
      SelectedImageId;     % Id of the selected image
      SelectedImagePrevId; % Id of the previously selected image
      ImgSelectionStr;     % Array of Label objects
      ImageSet;            % Array of Image objects
      app2_h;              % handle to access app2
   end
   
   methods (Access = private)
      
      % SetUnset_Selection: functin that manages the activaton of:
      %  - selection labels over the images 
      %  - path and filename of the selected image
      function SetUnset_Selection(app,SelectedImg)
         % Selet the image object from the ImageSet array
         tmp = app.ImageSet(SelectedImg);
         % Get the path and filename of the selected imae
         app.PathSelectedImage = get(tmp,'ImageSource');

         % Save the ID of the previouusly selected image
         if(app.SelectedImagePrevId ~= app.SelectedImageId)
            app.SelectedImagePrevId = app.SelectedImageId;
         else
            app.SelectedImagePrevId = -1;
         end
         
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         app.SelectedImageId = SelectedImg;

         % Selet the image label object from the ImgSelectionStr array
         tmp = app.ImgSelectionStr(SelectedImg);
         % Visualize the label of the selected image and hide the label of
         % the previously selected image and turns on the Import pushbutton
         if(strcmp(get(tmp,'Visible'),"off"))
            set(tmp,'Visible',"on",'Text','Selected (click again to unselect)');
            app.ImportButton.Enable = "on";
         else
            set(tmp,'Visible',"off")
            app.ImportButton.Enable = "off";
         end
         if(app.SelectedImagePrevId > 0)
            set(app.ImgSelectionStr(app.SelectedImagePrevId),'Visible','off');
         end
      end
   end
   

   % Callbacks that handle component events
   methods (Access = private)

      % Code that executes after component creation
      function startupFcn(app)
         % Initialize the handle to access app2
         app.app2_h = [];
         % Initialize the ID of the previously selected image
         app.SelectedImagePrevId = -1;
         % Initialize the ID of the selected image
         app.SelectedImageId = -1;
         % Store the image label objects in the ImgSelectionStr array
         % The array is used to easily access the label objects and avoid
         % duplication in the code
         app.ImgSelectionStr(1) = app.img_1_selected;
         app.ImgSelectionStr(2) = app.img_2_selected;
         app.ImgSelectionStr(3) = app.img_3_selected;
         app.ImgSelectionStr(4) = app.img_4_selected;
         app.ImgSelectionStr(5) = app.img_5_selected;
         app.ImgSelectionStr(6) = app.img_6_selected;

         % Store the image objects in the ImageSet array
         % The array is used to easily access the label objects and avoid
         % duplication in the code
         app.ImageSet(1) = app.Image_1;
         app.ImageSet(2) = app.Image_2;
         app.ImageSet(3) = app.Image_3;
         app.ImageSet(4) = app.Image_4;
         app.ImageSet(5) = app.Image_5;
         app.ImageSet(6) = app.Image_6;

      end

      % Button pushed function: ImportButton
      function ImportButtonPushed(app, event)
         % Turn off the Import pushbutton (will be turned on in the
         % SetUnset_Selection function
         app.ImportButton.Enable = "off";
         % Open the app2 that shows the selected image
         app.app2_h=app2(app);
      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_1
      function Image_1Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 1;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_2
      function Image_2Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 2;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_3
      function Image_3Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 3;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_4
      function Image_4Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 4;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_5
      function Image_5Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 5;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end

      % Image clicked function: Image_6
      function Image_6Clicked(app, event)
         % Set the ID of the selected image
         Sel_Img_Id = 6;
         % Call SetUnset_Selection to manage the image labels and get the
         % path and filename of the selected image
         SetUnset_Selection(app,Sel_Img_Id);

      end
   end

   % Component initialization
   methods (Access = private)

      % Create UIFigure and components
      function createComponents(app)

         % Get the file path for locating images
         pathToMLAPP = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));

         % Create MainAppUIFigure and hide until all components are created
         app.MainAppUIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
         app.MainAppUIFigure.IntegerHandle = 'on';
         app.MainAppUIFigure.Position = [100 100 580 431];
         app.MainAppUIFigure.Name = 'MainApp';
         app.MainAppUIFigure.Tag = 'App1_FIGURE';

         % Create Image_1
         app.Image_1 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_1.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_1Clicked, true);
         app.Image_1.Position = [34 301 118 92];
         app.Image_1.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_1.jpg');

         % Create Image_2
         app.Image_2 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_2.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_2Clicked, true);
         app.Image_2.Position = [34 176 118 92];
         app.Image_2.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_2.jpg');

         % Create Image_3
         app.Image_3 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_3.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_3Clicked, true);
         app.Image_3.Position = [34 53 118 92];
         app.Image_3.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_3.jpg');

         % Create Image_4
         app.Image_4 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_4.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_4Clicked, true);
         app.Image_4.Position = [413 301 118 92];
         app.Image_4.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_4.jpg');

         % Create Image_5
         app.Image_5 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_5.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_5Clicked, true);
         app.Image_5.Position = [413 176 118 92];
         app.Image_5.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_5.jpg');

         % Create Image_6
         app.Image_6 = uiimage(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.Image_6.ImageClickedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Image_6Clicked, true);
         app.Image_6.Position = [413 53 118 92];
         app.Image_6.ImageSource = fullfile(pathToMLAPP, 'IMG', 'img_6.jpg');

         % Create ImportButton
         app.ImportButton = uibutton(app.MainAppUIFigure, 'push');
         app.ImportButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ImportButtonPushed, true);
         app.ImportButton.BackgroundColor = [0.9294 0.6941 0.1255];
         app.ImportButton.FontSize = 14;
         app.ImportButton.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.ImportButton.Enable = 'off';
         app.ImportButton.Position = [211 203 158 39];
         app.ImportButton.Text = 'Import';

         % Create img_6_selected
         app.img_6_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_6_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_6_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_6_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_6_selected.Position = [350 144 195 22];
         app.img_6_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Create img_5_selected
         app.img_5_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_5_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_5_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_5_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_5_selected.Position = [350 267 195 22];
         app.img_5_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Create img_4_selected
         app.img_4_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_4_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_4_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_4_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_4_selected.Position = [350 393 195 22];
         app.img_4_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Create img_3_selected
         app.img_3_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_3_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_3_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_3_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_3_selected.Position = [48 144 195 22];
         app.img_3_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Create img_2_selected
         app.img_2_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_2_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_2_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_2_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_2_selected.Position = [48 267 195 22];
         app.img_2_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Create img_1_selected
         app.img_1_selected = uilabel(app.MainAppUIFigure);
         app.img_1_selected.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.img_1_selected.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.img_1_selected.Visible = 'off';
         app.img_1_selected.Position = [48 393 195 22];
         app.img_1_selected.Text = 'Selected (click again to unselect)';

         % Show the figure after all components are created
         app.MainAppUIFigure.Visible = 'on';
      end
   end

   % App creation and deletion
   methods (Access = public)

      % Construct app
      function app = MainApp_exported

         % Create UIFigure and components
         createComponents(app)

         % Register the app with App Designer
         registerApp(app, app.MainAppUIFigure)

         % Execute the startup function
         runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

         if nargout == 0
            clear app
         end
      end

      % Code that executes before app deletion
      function delete(app)

         % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
         delete(app.MainAppUIFigure)
      end
   end
end
```

**Second App code**

The `private property MainApp` is used to store the input parameter of the MainApp (whch is the MainApp handle)

The `startupFcn` simply retrieves the path and the name of the image to be displayed form the input parameter and sets the label above the image.

```
classdef app2_exported < matlab.apps.AppBase

   % Properties that correspond to app components
   properties (Access = public)
      App2ImageDisplayUIFigure  matlab.ui.Figure
      Label                     matlab.ui.control.Label
      CloseButton               matlab.ui.control.Button
      Image                     matlab.ui.control.Image
   end

   
   properties (Access = private)
      MainApp; % Handle of the calling app (app1)
   end
   

   % Callbacks that handle component events
   methods (Access = private)

      % Code that executes after component creation
      function startupFcn(app, CallingApp)
         % Set the handle of the calling app
         app.MainApp = CallingApp;
         % Load the select image
         app.Image.ImageSource = CallingApp.PathSelectedImage;
         % Print the name and the ID of the diplayed image
         [~,name,~] = fileparts(app.Image.ImageSource);
         img_id=CallingApp.SelectedImageId;
         str=sprintf('Name: %s\nPosition: %d',name,img_id);
         app.Label.Text = str;
         % Set the Label of the selected image in app1 as "Imported"
         tmp=CallingApp.ImgSelectionStr(img_id);
         set(tmp,'text','Imported');

      end

      % Button pushed function: CloseButton
      function CloseButtonPushed(app, event)
         % Get the handle of the label of the selected image in app1
         tmp=app.MainApp.ImgSelectionStr(app.MainApp.SelectedImageId);
         % Update the label of displayed image in the calling app before
         % closing the app2
         set(tmp,'text','App2 closed, select a in image');
         app.MainApp.app2_h = [];
         delete(app);
      end

      % Close request function: App2ImageDisplayUIFigure
      function App2ImageDisplayUIFigureCloseRequest(app, event)
         tmp=app.MainApp.ImgSelectionStr(app.MainApp.SelectedImageId);
         % Update the label of displayed image in the calling app before
         % closing the app2
         set(tmp,'text','App2 closed, select a in image');
         app.MainApp.app2_h = [];
         delete(app);
         
      end
   end

   % Component initialization
   methods (Access = private)

      % Create UIFigure and components
      function createComponents(app)

         % Create App2ImageDisplayUIFigure and hide until all components are created
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.IntegerHandle = 'on';
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.Position = [100 100 655 536];
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.Name = 'App2 - Image Display';
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.CloseRequestFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @App2ImageDisplayUIFigureCloseRequest, true);
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.HandleVisibility = 'on';
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.Tag = 'app2_FIGURE';

         % Create Image
         app.Image = uiimage(app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure);
         app.Image.Position = [33 122 390 295];

         % Create CloseButton
         app.CloseButton = uibutton(app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure, 'push');
         app.CloseButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @CloseButtonPushed, true);
         app.CloseButton.Position = [445 273 98 34];
         app.CloseButton.Text = 'Close';

         % Create Label
         app.Label = uilabel(app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure);
         app.Label.WordWrap = 'on';
         app.Label.Position = [59 448 524 73];
         app.Label.Text = '';

         % Show the figure after all components are created
         app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure.Visible = 'on';
      end
   end

   % App creation and deletion
   methods (Access = public)

      % Construct app
      function app = app2_exported(varargin)

         % Create UIFigure and components
         createComponents(app)

         % Register the app with App Designer
         registerApp(app, app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure)

         % Execute the startup function
         runStartupFcn(app, @(app)startupFcn(app, varargin{:}))

         if nargout == 0
            clear app
         end
      end

      % Code that executes before app deletion
      function delete(app)

         % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
         delete(app.App2ImageDisplayUIFigure)
      end
   end
end
```

The picture below shows the two Apps “at working”.

[image]

Comment: Again, please refrain from signing your posts. It is a convention here that your user card is enough.